# Event Logs since current time

Tags: c#, events

I have a little question about the **C#** event logs. I need to write a simple console application, that will read the current type of events (Application, System, Security) at the time, that I will set. I have this source , which is reading the event logs.

```
EventLog appLogs = new EventLog();
appLogs.Log = "Application";
foreach (EventLogEntry entry in appLogs.Entries)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\tEntry: " + entry.Message);
}
```

This will give me the events at current time. I need events from the time that I will give.

Thanks Before Hand:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the entries using Linq:

```
DateTime searchDate = ...
var entries = appLogs.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().Where(x => x.TimeWritten == searchDate);

foreach(var entry in entries)
{
    ...
}
```

The cast is necessary as `EventLogEntryCollection` is only `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<EventLogEntry>`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `entry.TimeWritten` property to filter which ones you want to print.

This can be done with a simple `if`or a `Linq` query.

```
        EventLog appLogs = new EventLog();
        appLogs.Log = "Application";
        DateTime timeToWrite = DateTime.Now;

        foreach (EventLogEntry entry in appLogs.Entries)
        {
            if (entry.TimeWritten == timeToWrite)
                Console.WriteLine("\tEntry: " + entry.Message);
        }
```

Linq

```
        EventLog appLogs = new EventLog();
        appLogs.Log = "Application";
        DateTime timeToWrite = DateTime.Now;

        var entriesToWrite = appLogs.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().Where(x => x.TimeWritten == timeToWrite);

        foreach (EventLogEntry entry in entriesToWrite)
        {
            if (entry.TimeWritten == timeToWrite)
                Console.WriteLine("\tEntry: " + entry.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you too, for you help, that helped me a lot.